# OpenGL changing color of generated texture

Tags: c++, opengl, fonts

I'm creating a sheet of characters and symbols from a font file, which works fine, except on the generated sheet all the pixels are black (with varying alpha). I would prefer them to be white so I can apply color multiplication and have different colored text. I realize that I can simply invert the color in the fragment shader, but I want to reuse the same shader for all my GUI elements.

I'm following this tutorial: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_02

Here's a snippet:

```
// Create map texture
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(1, &map);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, map);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, mapWidth, mapHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

// Draw bitmaps onto map
for (uint i = start; i < end; i++) {
    charInfo curChar = character[i];

    if (FT_Load_Char(face, i, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
        cout << "Loading character " << (char)i << " failed!" << endl;
        continue;
    }

    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, curChar.mapX, 0, curChar.width, curChar.height, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, glyph->bitmap.buffer);
}
```

The buffer of each glyph contains values of 0-255 for the alpha of the pixels. My question is, how do I generate white colored pixels instead of black? Is there a setting for this? (I've tried some blend modes but without success)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you create the texture with

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, mapWidth, mapHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

you can either change the GL_RGBA to GL_RED (or GL_LUMINANCE for pre-3.0 OpenGL) or you can create the RGBA buffer and copy the glyph data there.

I.e., you have

```
glyph->bitmap.buffer
```

then you do

```
unsigned char* glyphRGBA = new unsigned char[ curChar.width * curChar.height * 4];

for(int j = 0 ; j < curChar.height ; j++)
   for(int i = 0 ; i < curChar.width ; i++)
   {
       int ofs = j * curChar.width + i;
       for(int k = 0; k < 3 ; k++)
          glyphRGBA[ofs + k] = YourTextColor[k];
       // set alpha
       glyphRGBA[ofs + 3] = glyph->bitmap.buffer[ofs];
   }
```

In the code above `YourTextColor` is `unsigned char[3]` array with RGB components of the text color. The `glyphRGBA` array can be fed to glTexSubImage2D.

Comment: Changing GL_RGBA to GL_RED turns all the letters into black boxes, GL_LUMINANCE does the same. GL_LUMINANCE in glTexSubImage2D makes the text white, but the background is solid black. I also had the idea to modify the buffer, but was wondering if there was a simple setting I was missing.

Comment: GL_RED and LUMINANCE are equivalent and imply the text being non-translucent (no alpha-channel, no transparency), so the only way for you seems to be the allocation of a RGBA buffer - that's what I've called the second option. By the way, you haven't shown the way you're using this texture (you do text rendering with a custom pixel shader or just using the fixed-function pipeline and rendering the quad with GL_TEXTURE enabled ?)

Comment: I'm using a custom pixel shader with the output color being texture2D(uTex, vTexCoord) * uColor, that's why I need the character sheet to be white, otherwise the text will always be black regardless of uColor. I'll try generating a new RGBA buffer, thanks.